# Validating URL in dojo textbox

Tags: javascript, dojo

While trying to validate URL input by user in ValidationTextBox but there is nothing I could find for validating URL input like "www.google.com" and "http://www.google.com"

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"  regExp="dojox.validate.regexp.url" tooltipPosition="below" required="true" placeHolder="Enter Rule url" type="text" name="ruleUrl" id="ruleUrl">
```

The above doesn't work. Any alternative for validating URL's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you added `dojox/validate/regexp` to your modules in a `require()`? Because the code seems to work perfectly. I also made an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/PcxjN/).

Comment: you are a gem. Great catch